# Using default google map marker in JS

Tags: javascript, dictionary, icons, marker

I am trying to use the default marker icon of google map, I means the 10 kind of colors that you can find in android (blue, orange, red, green, etc.) but in a web browser using JS. By default the marker color is red and I want to use the others colors. I know there is an attribute  named "icon" where you can declare the path from your icons.jpg/png, but I want to use the default marker made by google.

I asked in google searcher but I didnt find any answer about this issue, only in android question, so how can I draw different colors in my map using google map in js? what path I must to use for this?

thank you StackOverflow.

Kind regards,

Abel Morgan.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/examples.html

Hope it helps.